# not able to change value using handleChange() with spread operator (...) in react class component() on object

Tags: reactjs, error-handling

> ****not able to get the values to change with the spread operator in handleChange()
> following is the error I get The specified value "" cannot be parsed, or is out of range.****

```
     class DashboardPersonalInfoItm extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          personalInfo: [],
        };
    
    
      }
    async componentDidMount() {
        let data = await  ApiCalls.getPersonalInfo();
        this.setState({personalInfo: data});
    
    
         }
```

> **following is where i am using spread operator and using to update the existing value of each field**

```
 handlePersonalInfoChange = event => {
    
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.personalInfo,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
 return (
   
    <form className={classes.container}  autoComplete="off">
</div>
    <TextField
              id="standard-required"
              disabled = {this.state.isDisabled}
              label="First Name"
              defaultValue="First Name"
              value = {this.state.personalInfo.firstName}
              className={classes.textField}
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.handlePersonalInfoChange}
              name="firstName"
            />
            <TextField
              id="standard-required"
              disabled = {this.state.isDisabled}
              label="Last Name"
              defaultValue="Last Name"
              value = {this.state.personalInfo.lastName}
              className={classes.textField}
              margin="normal"
              onChange={this.handlePersonalInfoChange}
              name="lastName"
            />
</div>
</form>
}
```

Comment: Do you want to append the value in your personalInfo state?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to append it to the state then the right way to do it is.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ 
      personalInfo: prevState.personalInfo, 
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value 
 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to update the state root level, Please try this. One concern you initial state object is an array but you're treating it like an object.

```
 this.setState({
      personalInfo: {
         ...this.state.personalInfo,
         [event.target.name]: event.target.value
      },
    });
```